# How to Speed up Window Leveling (Brightness,contrast)

Tags: javascript, json, html5-canvas, pixel, dicom

```
  pixelArr = [11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11..]  
    if (pixelArr != null)
            {
                for (var i = 0, n = pixelArr.length; i < n; i++)
                {
                    pix = pixelArr[i];
                    pix = ApplyWL(pix, imagewc, imageww);
                    pix = lutArr[pix];

                    // var red = (pix & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
                    v = i * 4;
                    imagedata[v] = pix & 0xff;
                    imagedata[v + 1] = (pix >>> 8) & 0xff;
                    imagedata[v + 2] = (pix >>> 16) & 0xff;
                    imagedata[v + 3] = 255;
                }
                //  offscreenCtx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
                offscreenCtx.putImageData(g, 0, 0);
            }
function ApplyWL(value, _valwindowCenter, _valwindowWidth)
        {
            Recalculate(_valwindowCenter, _valwindowWidth);
            if (value <= _windowStart)
                value = _minimumOutputValue;
            else if (value > _windowEnd)
                value = _maximumOutputValue;
            else
            {
                value = Math.round((((value - _windowCenterMin05) / _windowWidthMin1) + 0.5) * 255.0);
            }
            return value;
        }

        var _minimumOutputValue = 0;
        var _maximumOutputValue = 255;
        function Recalculate(_valwindowCenter, _valwindowWidth)
        {
            if (!_valid)
            {
                _windowCenterMin05 = _valwindowCenter - 0.5;
                _windowWidthMin1 = _valwindowWidth - 1;
                _windowWidthDiv2 = _windowWidthMin1 / 2;
                _windowStart = (_windowCenterMin05 - _windowWidthDiv2);
                _windowEnd = (_windowCenterMin05 + _windowWidthDiv2);
                _valid = true;
            }
        }


Width<input id="text1" type="text" />
    center<input id="text2" type="text" />
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Apply" onclick="ApplyWLCust();" />
    </br> time required<input id="text3" type="text" />
    <canvas style="height: 500px; width: 500px; display1: none; background-color: black;
                border: 1px solid red;" id="offscreenCanvas">
```

I have apply window levelling on Canvas Medical image(CR).
So that i have get an pixel array from C# Component.
On click of button I have call function ApplyWLCust();
In this function all process done getting result perfect.
For window leveling use bit shifting
while bit shift it takes around 585ms. 
I have to reduce this time what should i do 
any solution 
please suggest.

Comment: First thing would be not to use jQuery to iterate the loop but vanilla for(). Second: use typed array instead of Array.

Comment: How will u elaborate with some code

Comment: When you want to perform pixel-level operations, you should look into using WebGL with pixel shaders. That way you can use hardware acceleration.

Comment: Phillip thanks for reply Ken suggest me to use typed array..Which and How Will u please suggest  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays

Comment: I have to optimize for loop...suggest me any solutions

Comment: You might be better of asking this question on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You've made an attempt to reduce the time wasted for your recalcuate() method, but even so, it should not be in the inner loop. The window/level are not changing each pixel, so move that code out of the inner loop. The bigger problem with the code is the use of floating point values (probably defaults to double which is even slower) and the slow call to math.round(). Change the math to integer and reduce unnecessary code in the inner loop.

Comment: BitBank thanks for your reply. i have not understand this line  "The window/level are not changing each pixel, so move that code out of the inner loop."

Comment: You're attempting to recalculate the window bounds inside the for loop used to process the pixels. You try to mitigate the wasted time by adding a boolean named "valid". This code should not be inside that loop. Calculate the values once upon entering your code. The call to "Recalculate" should not be inside the main loop; calling a method and testing a boolean is wasting time unnecessarily.

Comment: BitBank has good point on that, however I believe that you wont get any significant/noticeable improvement on performance. Anyway, you should move Recalculate outside of loop (perhaps call it before and after for loop).

Answer (score 0):

I would consider parallel execution. It should at least cut execution time in half.

Check out this library: http://adambom.github.io/parallel.js/

---

I assume that you have large array.
Give to each parallel execution array and index **from** and **to**.
For example:

- ParallelExecution1 will process elements from 0 to 100
- ParallelExecution2 will process elements from 101 to 200
- ParallelExecution3 will process elements from 201 to 300
- ...